# SQL Get rows sorted by X with distinct values on column Y?

Tags: mysql, sql

Seems like a simple enough issue. Here's an image:

[image]

What I want: The rows outlined in black. Ignoring "duplicate" values of user_id (marked with colors). Sorted by date, DESC.

This seems logical, but the order is always wrong and takes the first occurrence of user_id vs the most recent:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `date` DESC) as `subtable`
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

Changing DESC/ASC of date didn't change anything. I thought by sorting the subquery before grouping I could get different results but nope.

Comment: Your subquery needs to select the max rows based on whichever value works for your purpose, then order those results at the end.

Comment: @cwalvoort Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by selecting the "max rows"? For example, what if I wanted to query the whole table and just get the most recent occurrences of user_id, as long as the rows returned had that column as distinct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hope this will encourage you (and anyone reading this, thinking of posting a sql question), sample data in text format, or a sqlfiddle link makes this kind of thing much easier, as does being specific about the database version being used.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13fab8/5

Without using analytic functions, this is one way to do it:

```
select m.*, t.last_date
from
  mytable m
  inner join (
    select user_id, max(date) as last_date from mytable
    group by user_id
  ) t on t.user_id = m.user_id
where
  m.date = t.last_date
```

Comment: thank you, this worked perfectly and it seems pretty straightforward, but it always does after you have the answer. I'll keep in mind providing better data/structure in the future, thanks again

Comment: One caution - if there are duplicate dates this may return more rows than expected from mytable.

Answer (score 0):

two ways to make it work
if you just want the maximal file_id per user_id you can do it like this

```
select user_id , max(file_id)
from mytable
group by user_id
```

if you want the whole row and you know there is no duplicates file_id per user_id:

```
select a.*
from mytable a
join (select user_id , max(file_id) as file_id
    from mytable
    group by user_id) b on a.user_id = b.user_id and a.file_id = b.file_id
```

there is also ways to do so with analytics functions - but it depends on the database you are using